# GA: sessionCount in segment with users::condition

Tags: google-analytics

I have a query as follows:

- `start-date`: "2016-04-01"
- `end-date`: "2016-04-30"
- `dimensions`: "ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel"
- `metrics`: "ga:uniqueEvents"
- `segment`: "users::condition::ga:sessionCount==1"

After reading [description of sessionCount](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032796?hl=en) I'm not sure what this segment is exactly doing.

Does it:

1. Select all April 2016 sessions of users who had their first session
   in April 2016
2. Select all April 2016 sessions of users who ever had their first session
3. Select April 2016 sessions with `ga:sessionCount==1` of users who had their first session in April 2016
4. something else?

Comment: You can add ga:sessionCount as a dimension to you query to test how different segment scope (User and Session) effect session count in your data.

Answer (score 1):

Session Count = 1 means that the GA tracker did not detect an existing GA cookie for that site.

The condition of Session Count == 1 means the (first ever session of a user on that device/browser since the cookies were cleared).

Users scope means all sessions for any user that matches the condition.

The date range applies to both the results and the condition, so the first session occurred during April AND the results would include any other sessions by those users during April.